# @media (320px) not working with my columns to make them 100% width

Tags: html, css, media

Hi I am almost finished with my website but I have a small issue of the columns not displaying at 100% when on a mobile device, I do not know what I have done wrong in the css below but the max-width 320px does not seem to be making the column go 100% when on mobile.

here is a link to my site to see what happens

http://www.ico.mmu.ac.uk/08506125/portfolio/index.html

I know it's a really simple solution...

```
@media(max-width : 320px){
.column.half { width: 100%;}
 }

/* Column sizes */

@media (min-width: 40rem) 
 .column {
float:left;
padding-left:1em ;
padding-right:1em;
}

.column.full { width: 100%; }
.column.two-thirds { width: 66.7%; }
.column.half { width: 50%;}
.column.third { width: 33.3%; }
.column.fourth { width: 25%; }
.column.flow-opposite { float: right; } 


/* Column sizes end */

/* Medium screens (640px) */
@media (min-width: 40rem) {
html { font-size: 112%; }
.third {  float:left; display:inline;}
.half {  float:left; display:inline;}
.two-thirds { float:left; display:inline;}
.image {  border-style: double; border-color:white;} 
}

/* Large screens (1024px) */
@media (min-width: 64rem) {
html { font-size: 120%; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put this condition in the bottom because you override it with your default width.

```
.column.half { width: 50%;}

@media(max-width : 320px){
    .column.half { width: 100%;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! knew it was something simple.

Answer (score 0):

please notice "half" class stop getting "float left" on 640px so you've got the issue already from there...because there are devices with bigger screen resolution, maybe it can be better for you to change 320px to 640px:

```
@media (max-width: 40rem){
    .column.half
    {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```